# getting duplicate rows for each row using linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0, c#-6.0

I have  db schema having tables like this below, i am trying to get the results using left join or normal join on these table using the below query. Somehow getting duplicate rows like as mentioned below.

```
Requests (table)               RequestStage (table)                      

 -------------                ----------------
 id                            RequestStageid
 createdAt(datetime)           name (values: RequestSubmitted,Inreview)
 RequestTypeId
 MasterSectionID
 RequestStatusID
 RequestStageID
 id (FK)(localCodes)


  MasterSections (table)
 -------------------------
 MasterSectionId 
  name  (values: code1,Code2)

 LocalCodes (table)
 ---------
  Id
  MasterSectionid
  Name
  description
  ...
  ...
```

I have inserted three rows into local code table at the same time three rows inserted into request table with `requestStage` as `RequestSubmitted`

Now i am trying to pull the rows which are having the status `RequestSubmitted` using below query. I should be able to get the `3` rows, instead of it i am getting `9` rows(i.e) `I am getting 1 row three times`.

if i apply `distinct` i am getting `3` rows but is there any other way to achieve this with out applying `distinct`

```
   var results = (from re in _dbContext.Requests
                  join rt in _dbContext.RequestTypes on re.RequestTypeId equals rt.RequestTypeId
                  join rs in _dbContext.RequestStages on re.RequestStageId equals rs.RequestStageId
                  join ms in _dbContext.MasterSections on re.MasterSectionId equals ms.MasterSectionId
                  join lc in _dbContext.LocalCodes on ms.MasterSectionId equals lc.MasterSectionId
                  where rs.Name == "RequestSubmitted"
                  select new SectionResponse
                  {
                        Section = lc.Name,
                        Description = lc.Description,
                        CreatedBy = "",
                        Type = rt.Name.ToString(),
                        Status = rs.Name,
                        Age = (DateTime.Now.Date - re.CreatedAt.Date).TotalDays.ToString() + "Days"
                   }).ToList();
```

**Another attempt:**

```
(from re in _dbContext.Requests
 join rt in _dbContext.RequestTypes on re.RequestTypeId equals rt.RequestTypeId into reqTypes
 from x in reqTypes.DefaultIfEmpty()
 join rs in _dbContext.RequestStages on re.RequestStageId equals rs.RequestStageId into reqStages
 from y in reqStages.DefaultIfEmpty()
 join ms in _dbContext.MasterSections on re.MasterSectionId equals ms.MasterSectionId into mstSections
 from z in mstSections.DefaultIfEmpty()
 join lc in _dbContext.LocalCodes on z.MasterSectionId equals lc.MasterSectionId into locCodes
 from a in locCodes.DefaultIfEmpty()
 where y.Name == "RequestSubmitted"
 select new SectionResponse
 {
      Section = a.Name,
      Description = a.Description,
      CreatedBy = "",
      Type = x.Name.ToString(),
      Status = y.Name,
      Age = (DateTime.Now.Date - re.CreatedAt.Date).TotalDays.ToString() + "Days"
 }).ToList();
```

I am not sure where i am doing wrong in these queries, Could any one please suggest any idea on how to get only three rows. Also please let me know if you need any more information.

Many thanks

Domain models :

```
public class Request
{
    public Guid RequestId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid DataId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public Guid MasterSectionId { get; set; }
    public Guid RequestStatusId { get; set; }
    public Guid RequestStageId { get; set; }
    public Guid RequestTypeId { get; set; }
    public  MasterSection MasterSection { get; set; }
    public  RequestStatus Status { get; set; }
    public  RequestStage Stage { get; set; }
    public  RequestType RequestType { get; set; }
}

public class RequestStage
{

    public Guid RequestStageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}
public class MasterSection
{
    public Guid MasterSectionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LocalCode> LocalCodes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}
public class RequestStatus
{
    public Guid  RequestStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}
public class LocalCode : IMasterObject
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid MasterSectionId { get; set; }
    public MasterSection MasterSection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could any one please let me know if you need any more info

Comment: without seeing the details in each table, its hard to say why that would occur. From experience, normally it has somethign to do with 1:many relationships. One thing to do would be to run the query in SQL or DB backend one table at a time and continue joining till you see whats going on. MasterSections might be the problem child.

Comment: The problem with the MasterSections table and LocalCodes table, if LocalCodes table has repeated MasterSectionId (same id) this will cause the duplicate record, because how the Requests table will map to the localcodes with multi mastersectionid? which local will represent the mastersection id?

Comment: i might be seeing double but even if you changed the query from lc.Name to rs.Name, the duplicates would still come from various Stages that might exists under MasterSections. Each of those master sections will display each.all localCodes

Comment: @CyberProgs  I updated my table structure i forgot to mention there is foreign key in request table that is storing localcode id as well. Could you please verify and please suggest any ideas with this relationship

Comment: @Jawad I updated my table structure i forgot to mention there is foreign key in request table that is storing localcode id as well. Could you please verify and please suggest any ideas with this relationship

Comment: What is the relationship between MasterSections  and LocalCodes? is it one to one or one to many ?

Comment: @CyberProgs masterSection is having values like (1, localCode, 2, code2..) and localcode is having individual local code data ..

Comment: @CyberProgs i updated my models for better understanding ..

Comment: @Jawad i updated my data models, could you please suggest any ideas on this one

Comment: @Jawad could you please let me know where i am doing wrong with these datamodels

Comment: Are you able to provide the 9 records you are getting instead of 3. Structure and data might help decipher why you are getting dups

Comment: @ i removed join with master sections so i can be able to get the unique rows now anyway thanks for the help

Comment: So it was the master sections table... knew it from the beginning ;) glad you got it working

Answer (score 1):

I tried using navigational properties and based on the description came up with below domain models.
Please try this: (code is not tested though)

```
// Junction Table
public class Requests
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public DateTime createdAt {get; set;}

   [ForeginKey("RequestType")]
   public int RequestTypeId {get; set;}
   public virtual RequestType RequestType {get; set;}

   [ForeginKey("MasterSections")]
   public int MasterSectionID {get; set;}
   public virtual MasterSections MasterSections {get; set;}

   public int RequestStatusID {get; set;}

   [ForeginKey("RequestStage")]
   public int RequestStageID {get; set;}
   public virtual RequestStage RequestStage {get; set;}
}

public class RequestStage
{
   [Key]
   public int RequestStageID {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
}

public class MasterSections
{
   public int MasterSectionId {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
}

public class LocalCodes
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get; set;}

   [ForeginKey("MasterSections")]
   public int MasterSectionId {get; set;}
   public virtual MasterSections MasterSections {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
}
```

If you want to use IQueryable then you can not calculate Age at the time of projection using .NET framework's DATE functions. You will need to use EF DATE related DBFunctions.

```
db.Requests.Include(r => r.RequestStage).Include(r => r.MasterSections)
  .Where(r => r.RequestStage.name == "RequestSubmitted")
  .Join(_dbContext.LocalCodes.Include(l => l.MasterSections), rqst => rqst.MasterSectionID, lc => lc.MasterSectionId,
   (rt, lc) => new SectionResponse
                  {
                        Section = lc.Name,
                        Description = lc.Description,
                        CreatedBy = "",
                        Type = rt.Name.ToString(),
                        Status = rt.rs.Name,
                        /* Age property can not be done from within Queryable as .Date is not available in EF. If you want this, convert the query to enumerable and then project.*/
                        // Age = (DateTime.Now.Date - re.CreatedAt.Date).TotalDays.ToString() + "Days"
                   }).ToList();
```

By converting to Enumerable, you can calculate Age at the time projection like below:

```
db.Requests.Include(r => r.RequestStage).Include(r => r.MasterSections)
  .Where(r => r.RequestStage.name == "RequestSubmitted")
  .Join(_dbContext.LocalCodes.Include(l => l.MasterSections), rqst => rqst.MasterSectionID, lc => lc.MasterSectionId,
   (rt, lc) => new {rt = rt, rs = rt.RequestStage, lc = lc, ms = lc.MasterSections}).AsEnumerable().
  Select(anonType =>  new SectionResponse
                  {
                        Section = anonType.lc.Name,
                        Description = anonType.lc.Description,
                        CreatedBy = "",
                        Type = anonType.rt.Name.ToString(),
                        Status = anonType.rs.Name,
                        Age = (DateTime.Now.Date - anonType.rt.CreatedAt.Date).TotalDays.ToString() + "Days"
                   }).ToList();
```

Based on update to Request model, it can be achieved using below query:

```
db.Requests.Include(r => r.RequestStage).Include(r => r.RequestType).Include(r => r.LocalCodes.MasterSections)
  .Where(r => r.RequestStage.name == "RequestSubmitted")
  .Select(r => new {r = r, rt = r.RequestType, rs = rt.RequestStage, lc = r.lc, ms = r.lc.MasterSections}).AsEnumerable().
  Select(anonType =>  new SectionResponse
                  {
                        Section = anonType.lc.Name,
                        Description = anonType.lc.Description,
                        CreatedBy = "",
                        Type = anonType.rt.Name.ToString(),
                        Status = anonType.rs.Name,
                        Age = $"{DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(anonType.r.CreatedAt.Date).TotalDays} Days"
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response, I updated my table structure i forgot to mention there is foreign key in request table that is storing localcode id as well. Could you please verify and please suggest any ideas

Comment: Updated my post. Please use the last query.

Comment: getting error at `Include(r => r.LocalCodes.MasterSections)` here

Comment: Does LocalCodes have Foreign Key reference to MasterSections? If yes, is the property name matches with your DB Foreign Key name? Please update domain models accordingly. With the info that is provided here, I created models.

Comment: i figured that out thank you , but only `Requests` table is having `createdAt` column and getting error here `anonType.rt.CreatedAt.Date`

Comment: @EnigmaState: You are correct. That should be just anonType.CreatedAt.Date. I copy+pasted from previous query which was using JOIN. I updated the query now.

Comment: I am using your second query and i am still getting error `anonType.rt.CreatedAt.Date` at here and even i cannot be able to get  date from this one `anonType.CreatedAt.Date`

Comment: Updated again. Please post your domain models so I could provide you updated query.

Comment: I updated my models in question also could you  please correct me anything wrong in these models..

Comment: Anonymous type only contains rt,rs,ms and lc only but i do want createdAt column that is coming from request table

Comment: Updated my query to return request (variable name is r) also. If I am not wrong, I remember you mentioning about having reference to LocalCode from Request. But your model does not have that reference. Also, how are you saving GUIDs in database - via varchar?

Comment: we are not maintaining tight relationship between `local code` and `request`and i I am getting error at here `Include(r => r.LocalCodes.MasterSections)` I am using your second query, could you please modify your second query

Comment: I am getting error at here in your second query `(DateTime.Now.Date - anonType.rt.CreatedAt.Date)`

Comment: still getting duplicate rows for all those queries

Comment: I am still getting duplicates for your second query even i apply distinct as well

Comment: if you have time could you please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276623/getting-the-duplicate-ids-for-three-records-using-linq this is where i am currently .. many thanks

Comment: Sorry, looking into now.